# Magento 1.8 static block in widget not showing?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, static-block, widget, cms-block

I have created simple static block and trying to show it through widget inside Left Column but its not showing. In fact any static block is not working through widget. I have created magento theme in 1.9 with static blocks it was working fine now I'm deploying it to magento 1.8 any reasons ?

I'm attaching it in Left Column,

> cms->widgets creating new instance
>
> type:cms static block;
>
> design: customTheme/default (i have also tried with base/default,
>   default/default )
>
> Widget Instance Title:left-block
>
> Assign to Store Views: All Store Views;
>
> sort order:1
>
> Add Layout Update:
>
> Display On:Non-Anchor Categories
>
> Block Reference:Left Column
>
> widget option: Left Block

Comment: Does it work in a different location? (for example the header)

Answer (score 1):

Widgets are specific to **Packages/Themes** and do not follow Magento's Hierarchy (Fallback) system from my experience.

**Make sure the widget you've created is assigned specifically to the Package & Theme your Store/Store View has assigned under System > Configuration > Design.**

IF you're using a Custom Design on a Product, Category, CMS Page, or design set in System > Design you'll want to make sure you are assign your widget instance to reflect the same value.  Be careful though, you cannot easily reassign the Package/Theme of a widget instance in Magento's admin.